# Fastest implementation of a way to adjust pyplot overlapping annotation text? Preferably one that can utilize multi-core and/or GPU resources?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I usually use adjustText to produce labels (annotations) that do not overlap in pyplot.

https://github.com/Phlya/adjustText

But at 10,000 data points for a scatter plot, it because very slow.

I was wondering if there's anything faster, that perhaps takes advantage of multi-core and/or GPU resources?

Comment: What makes `adjustText` slow is the fact that the extent of a text can only be known after it being drawn. So one needs to draw every text first before knowing the positions and being able to adjust them. There is no way to parallelize the drawing of matplotlib artists of the same figure, so I don't expect any improvement for using multiple cores. On the other hand, one could review why 10000 text labels would even make sense in a plot. Nobody would be able to read them, even if they don't overlap.

Comment: Thanks! "On the other hand, one could review why 10000 text labels would even make sense in a plot. Nobody would be able to read them, even if they don't overlap." this is for big map that people can zoom in on.

Comment: So people will use matplotlib to zoom in? Or what interface are you thinking about?

Comment: Much in analogy to maps (e.g. openstreetmap, google map etc), those maps do not show the name of every street on the lowest zoom level. Only once you zoom in, there is actually some text rendered.

Comment: It'll produce a big picture that I can save as PNG file and then convert to JPEG. People can zoom in on the JPEG.

Comment: How long does it take to create the png? How often do you need to produce this image?

Comment: It doesn't seem to take that long. I don't know the exact time but I never had an issue with it. I use  `pyplot.savefig` . At the moment I've been setting to the size with `pyplot.figure(figsize=(230, 230))`

Comment: If it doesn't take long, what issue are you asking about here?

Comment: Oh I thought you were talking about how long does the `pyplot.savefig` or `pyplot.figure(figsize=(230, 230))` command takes. The adjust text is what's causing the slowdown, specifically `adjust_text(texts , arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', color='red'))`. I ran on Google Colab and it went 12 hours (max time to run something on GPU) without finishing executing. I'm going to try again on CPU mode since I don't think Colab has a limit on that. This was for 6000 points btw. I would still like to have all 10000 points ploted. I only need it plotted only once.

Comment: Ok, so if you want someone to look deeper into that, you may of course create a [mcve] for people to play around with. I could imagine that applying the `adjust_text` to only a subset of the texts at a time would significantly fasten the process.

Answer (score 0):

Just created a package for this purpose that is fast due to a more brute force implementation with broadcasting in numpy, [textalloc](https://github.com/ckjellson/textalloc).

It generates a plot like below ([scattertext](https://github.com/JasonKessler/scattertext) design) with ~2000 points in 2.9s on a laptop. Here I use the base setting not to plot texts that end up overlapping after running the algorithm, but if you want to plot 10000 text labels that do not overlap I assume you could use even smaller text size and the draw_all setting.

[image: scattertext]